# Second time values are not taken correctly from an array randomly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have four boxes I selected 4 items from an array **items**.

I have placed the randomly selected item inside 4 boxes.

Class **box002** can be dragged and dropped to corresponding number in four boxes displayed. then digit in box dissappears.

My problem is that after dropping all four boxes correctly, second time values are not filled correctly, ie, reandomly selected values from array `**items**` does notmatch with `**tempimages**` stored for displaying in `**box002**` for dragging and dropping.

How to solve this? And make second level work?

```js
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
  }
];

var tempimages = [];
var array2 = [];
array2 = items.slice();

var backimgcount = 1;
var len = array2.length;

var item;
var displaycounter = 0;




var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/g/200/300'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}


function rvalue() {


  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff66ff";
    //elements[i].borderRadius = "2px";
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #e3a89e ";
    //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

  }


  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");


  for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    //item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')'; 
    tempimages.push({
      data: item,
      index: randomIndex
    });

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;


}


function displayAllImages() {
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {

    rvalue();
  }
  //tempimages = tempimages.concat(tempimages.splice(0,2));
  //item = tempimages.splice(0, 1);

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }


  var arr = tempimages;
  arr = shuffle(arr);

  item = arr.shift();
  image = document.getElementById('slide');
  image.src = item.data.url;
  image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;


};

$(function() {

  displayAllImages();

});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id).classList.add('dashed');
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;



  if (x == y) {
    //el.parentNode.removeChild; 

    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    //ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
    array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);


    //alert("sucessfull");
    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      hiddenimage();
      //changeImage();
      changeImage();
    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {
    playAudio2();
    alert("WRONG TIME PLACED");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size:contain;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.3vh;
  left: 72.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 23.0vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="13">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>
```

Comment: Pls, fix your code:1) issue in rvalue function ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex; (should use boxtags insted ptags) 2) hiddenimage are missed

Comment: @mrgrechkinn  if change ptags to boxtags then ondrop number IE <P> ELEMENT will not get deleted

Comment: it will be deleted if you drop on the box, pls, try to fix your code: clear it; remove missed functions (I can't even launch for test)

Comment: Please drop on exact top of numver in box in blue color it will work

Comment: Your snippet is not working, as soon as I click or drag anything I get `"message": "Script error.",` on the snippet's console. We can't help you if the example you are providing isn't even doing what you said it should be doing, let alone fix what isn't working here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't even imagine how are you work with this code. Before posting example on stackoverflow try to clear it (remove unused code, remove function that doesn't exists).

Issues:
1) drag function, .classlist was commented out
2) playAudio2 was commented out
3) hiddenimage function was commented out
4) ok, maybe index should be on p tag, but it's can be figured out from example (maybe you should add to boxtags too.

So, on this example you can see, that second time values working properly, but when all images are finished there is some new issues.

```js
    var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=10'
  }
];

var tempimages = [];
var array2 = [];
array2 = items.slice();

var backimgcount = 1;
var len = array2.length;

var item;
var displaycounter = 0;




var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/g/200/300'];
var index = 0;

function buildImage() {
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}

function changeImage() {
  index++;
  if (index >= images.length) index = 0;
  document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/' + images[index] + ')';
}


function rvalue() {


  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff66ff";
    //elements[i].borderRadius = "2px";
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #e3a89e ";
    //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

  }


  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

debugger;
  for (var index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    //item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')'; 
    tempimages.push({
      data: item,
      index: randomIndex
    });

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;


}


function displayAllImages() {
  if (tempimages.length == 0) {

    rvalue();
  }
  //tempimages = tempimages.concat(tempimages.splice(0,2));
  //item = tempimages.splice(0, 1);

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }


  var arr = tempimages;
  arr = shuffle(arr);

  item = arr.shift();
  image = document.getElementById('slide');
  image.src = item.data.url;
  image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;


};

$(function() {

  displayAllImages();

});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);//.classList.add('dashed');
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;



  if (x == y) {
    //el.parentNode.removeChild; 

    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';

    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    //ev.currentTarget.removeChild(pParagraph);
    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;
    array2.splice(arrayvalue, 1);


    //alert("sucessfull");
    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      //hiddenimage();
      //changeImage();
      changeImage();
    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {
    //playAudio2();
    alert("WRONG TIME PLACED");
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size:contain;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27.3vh;
  left: 72.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 14.0vw;
  height: 23.0vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:30px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="13">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>
```